# Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops

Let's say I have the following simple table variable:

```
declare @databases table
(
    DatabaseID    int,
    Name        varchar(15),   
    Server      varchar(15)
)
-- insert a bunch rows into @databases
```

Is declaring and using a cursor my only option if I wanted to iterate through the rows? Is there another way?

Comment: Although I'm not sure the problem you see with the above approach; See if this helps.. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3111031

Comment: Could you provide us the reason why you want to iterate over the rows, other solution that don't require iteration might exists (and which are faster by a large margin in most cases)

Comment: agree with pop... may not need a cursor depending on the situation. but theres no problem with using cursors if you need to

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: I was reading about looping through a table variable with a cursor and came across this, is there a benefit to using the select, update iteration covered below instead of a cursor?

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor

Comment: You don't state why you want to avoid a cursor. Be aware that a cursor might be the simplest way to iterate. You may have heard that cursors are 'bad', but it is really iteration over tables that is bad compared to set-based operations. If you can't avoid iteration, a cursor might be the best way. Locking is another problem with cursors, but that is not relevant when using a table variable.

Comment: Using a cursor isn't your _only_ option, but if you have no way to avoid a row-by-row approach, then it will be your best option. CURSORs are a built-in construct that are more efficient and less error-prone than doing your own silly WHILE loop. Most of the time you just need to use the `STATIC` option to remove the constant re-checking of base tables and the locking that are there by default and cause most people to mistakenly believe that CURSORs are evil. @JacquesB very close: rechecking to see if the result row still exists + locking are the issues. And `STATIC` usually fixes that :-).

Comment: This is super old, but I'll add this here just incase someone else stumbles across this in the future.

Unless your table is really small, iterating over each row without the use of a cursor is probably a bad idea.


Using the accepted answer below could result in taking several hours to complete where as using a cursor would complete in a few seconds.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

First of all you should be absolutely sure you need to iterate through each row — set based operations will perform faster in every case I can think of and will normally use simpler code.

Depending on your data it may be possible to loop using just `SELECT` statements as shown below:

```
Declare @Id int

While (Select Count(*) From ATable Where Processed = 0) > 0
Begin
    Select Top 1 @Id = Id From ATable Where Processed = 0

    --Do some processing here

    Update ATable Set Processed = 1 Where Id = @Id 

End
```

Another alternative is to use a temporary table:

```
Select *
Into   #Temp
From   ATable

Declare @Id int

While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @Id = Id From #Temp

    --Do some processing here

    Delete #Temp Where Id = @Id

End
```

The option you should choose really depends on the structure and volume of your data.

**Note:** If you are using SQL Server you would be better served using:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)
```

Using `COUNT` will have to touch every single row in the table, the `EXISTS` only needs to touch the first one (see [Josef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65294/963542) below).

Comment: "Select Top 1 @Id = Id From ATable" should be "Select Top 1 @Id = Id From ATable Where Processed = 0"

Comment: If using SQL Server, see Josef's answer below for a small tweak to the above.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better than using a cursor ?

Comment: Gave this one a downvote. Why should he avoid using a cursor?  He's talking about iterating over **table variable**, not a traditional table. I don't believe the normal downsides of cursors applies here. If row-by-row processing is truly required (and as you point out he should be certain about that first) then using a cursor is a much better solution than the ones you describe here.

Comment: @peterh You are correct. And in fact, you can usually avoid those "normal downsides" by using the `STATIC` option which copies the result set to a temp table, and hence you are no longer locking or re-checking base tables :-).

Comment: After reading this article (https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options) I tried testing the same query with a #temp table. The cursor solution was by far faster then any #temp table solution I tried. Yes, there are ways to avoid cursors but are they all good for performance? I highly doubt that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to do `WHILE EXISTS(SELECT Top 1 * FROM #Temp)` instead of `SELECT *` so that you're not reading the whole table every time just to see if the top row exists?

Answer (score 155):

Just a quick note, if you are using SQL Server (2008 and above), the examples that have:

```
While (Select Count(*) From #Temp) > 0
```

Would be better served with

```
While EXISTS(SELECT * From #Temp)
```

The Count will have to touch every single row in the table, the `EXISTS` only needs to touch the first one.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment/enhancement on Martynw answer.

Comment: The content of this note forces better formatting functionality than a comment, I would suggest to append at the Answer.

Comment: In later versions of SQL, the query optimiser is clever enough to know that when you write the first thing, you actually mean the second and optimises it as such to avoid the table scan.

Answer (score 50):

This is how I do it:

```
declare @RowNum int, @CustId nchar(5), @Name1 nchar(25)

select @CustId=MAX(USERID) FROM UserIDs     --start with the highest ID
Select @RowNum = Count(*) From UserIDs      --get total number of records
WHILE @RowNum > 0                          --loop until no more records
BEGIN   
    select @Name1 = username1 from UserIDs where USERID= @CustID    --get other info from that row
    print cast(@RowNum as char(12)) + ' ' + @CustId + ' ' + @Name1  --do whatever

    select top 1 @CustId=USERID from UserIDs where USERID < @CustID order by USERID desc--get the next one
    set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1                               --decrease count
END
```

No Cursors, no temporary tables, no extra columns.
The USERID column must be a unique integer, as most Primary Keys are.

Comment: Good solution, for me the better approach was to use `Min(Id)` because my `Id` column had an `ascending` clustered index, So it was an extra operation for the queries to reverse the ordering.

Comment: This won't work if your primary key is a UNIQUEIDENTIFER

Answer (score 34):

Define your temp table like this -

```
declare @databases table
(
    RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    DatabaseID    int,
    Name        varchar(15),   
    Server      varchar(15)
)

-- insert a bunch rows into @databases
```

Then do this -

```
declare @i int
select @i = min(RowID) from @databases
declare @max int
select @max = max(RowID) from @databases

while @i <= @max begin
    select DatabaseID, Name, Server from @database where RowID = @i --do some stuff
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I would do it:

```
Select Identity(int, 1,1) AS PK, DatabaseID
Into   #T
From   @databases

Declare @maxPK int;Select @maxPK = MAX(PK) From #T
Declare @pk int;Set @pk = 1

While @pk <= @maxPK
Begin

    -- Get one record
    Select DatabaseID, Name, Server
    From @databases
    Where DatabaseID = (Select DatabaseID From #T Where PK = @pk)

    --Do some processing here
    -- 

    Select @pk = @pk + 1
End
```

---

[Edit] Because I probably skipped the word "variable" when I first time read the question, here is an updated response...

---

```
declare @databases table
(
    PK            int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    DatabaseID    int,
    Name        varchar(15),   
    Server      varchar(15)
)
-- insert a bunch rows into @databases
--/*
INSERT INTO @databases (DatabaseID, Name, Server) SELECT 1,'MainDB', 'MyServer'
INSERT INTO @databases (DatabaseID, Name, Server) SELECT 1,'MyDB',   'MyServer2'
--*/

Declare @maxPK int;Select @maxPK = MAX(PK) From @databases
Declare @pk int;Set @pk = 1

While @pk <= @maxPK
Begin

    /* Get one record (you can read the values into some variables) */
    Select DatabaseID, Name, Server
    From @databases
    Where PK = @pk

    /* Do some processing here */
    /* ... */ 

    Select @pk = @pk + 1
End
```

Comment: so basically youre doing a cursor, but without all of the benefits of a cursor

Comment: ... without locking the tables that are used while processing... as this is one of the *benefits* of a cursor :)

Comment: Tables? It's a table VARIABLE - there is no concurrent access possible.

Comment: DenNukem, you're right, I think I "skipped" the word "variable" when I read the question at that time...
I will add some notes to the my initial response

Comment: I have to agree with DenNukem and Shawn. Why, why, why do you go to these lengths to avoid using a cursor?  Again: he wants to iterate over a table variable, not a traditional table !!!

Comment: @nolan6000 - All of you commenting here are right, but read the question again. The user specifically asked about how to "loop through a table variable without a cursor" and if the cursor is his only option. I think my answer "answers" the question.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point. But why help him to a sub-optimal solution when a cursor is actually the optimal solution IN THIS PARTICULAR CASE. I'm thinking the user - like so many others - has been told to *always* avoid cursors but this is a too simplistic teaching when it comes to table variables, IMHO.

Comment: @nolan6000 - I think part of using this website properly is to learn to ask the right question... I usually answer a question, I don't try to change the question :)

Answer (score 12):

If you have no choice than to go row by row creating a FAST_FORWARD cursor. It will be as fast as building up a while loop and much easier to maintain over the long haul.

FAST_FORWARD
    Specifies a FORWARD_ONLY, READ_ONLY cursor with performance optimizations enabled. FAST_FORWARD cannot be specified if SCROLL or FOR_UPDATE is also specified.

Comment: Yeah!  As I commented elsewhere I have yet to see any arguments as to why **NOT** to use a cursor when the case is to iterate over a **table variable**. A `FAST_FORWARD`cursor is a fine solution. (upvote)

Answer (score 7):

This will work in SQL SERVER 2012 version.

```
declare @Rowcount int 
select @Rowcount=count(*) from AddressTable;

while( @Rowcount>0)
  begin 
 select @Rowcount=@Rowcount-1;
 SELECT * FROM AddressTable order by AddressId desc OFFSET @Rowcount ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach without having to change your schema or using temp tables:

```
DECLARE @rowCount int = 0
  ,@currentRow int = 1
  ,@databaseID int
  ,@name varchar(15)
  ,@server varchar(15);

SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*)
FROM @databases;

WHILE (@currentRow <= @rowCount)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1
     @databaseID = rt.[DatabaseID]
    ,@name = rt.[Name]
    ,@server = rt.[Server]
  FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY t.[DatabaseID], t.[Name], t.[Server]
       ) AS [RowNumber]
      ,t.[DatabaseID]
      ,t.[Name]
      ,t.[Server]
    FROM @databases t
  ) rt
  WHERE rt.[RowNumber] = @currentRow;

  EXEC [your_stored_procedure] @databaseID, @name, @server;

  SET @currentRow = @currentRow + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a while loop:

```
While (Select Count(*) From #TempTable) > 0
Begin
    Insert Into @Databases...

    Delete From #TempTable Where x = x
End
```

Answer (score 4):

Lightweight, without having to make extra tables, if you have an integer `ID` on the table

```
Declare @id int = 0, @anything nvarchar(max)
WHILE(1=1) BEGIN
  Select Top 1 @anything=[Anything],@id=@id+1 FROM Table WHERE ID>@id
  if(@@ROWCOUNT=0) break;

  --Process @anything

END
```

Answer (score 3):

I really do not see the point why you would need to resort to using dreaded `cursor`.
But here is another option if you are using SQL Server version 2005/2008

Use **Recursion**

```
declare @databases table
(
    DatabaseID    int,
    Name        varchar(15),   
    Server      varchar(15)
)

--; Insert records into @databases...

--; Recurse through @databases
;with DBs as (
    select * from @databases where DatabaseID = 1
    union all
    select A.* from @databases A 
        inner join DBs B on A.DatabaseID = B.DatabaseID + 1
)
select * from DBs
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-- [PO_RollBackOnReject]  'FININV10532'
alter procedure PO_RollBackOnReject
@CaseID nvarchar(100)

AS
Begin
SELECT  *
INTO    #tmpTable
FROM   PO_InvoiceItems where CaseID = @CaseID

Declare @Id int
Declare @PO_No int
Declare @Current_Balance Money


While (Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PO_LineNo DESC) From #tmpTable) > 0
Begin
        Select Top 1 @Id = PO_LineNo, @Current_Balance = Current_Balance,
        @PO_No = PO_No
        From #Temp
        update PO_Details
        Set  Current_Balance = Current_Balance + @Current_Balance,
            Previous_App_Amount= Previous_App_Amount + @Current_Balance,
            Is_Processed = 0
        Where PO_LineNumber = @Id
        AND PO_No = @PO_No
        update PO_InvoiceItems
        Set IsVisible = 0,
        Is_Processed= 0
        ,Is_InProgress = 0 , 
        Is_Active = 0
        Where PO_LineNo = @Id
        AND PO_No = @PO_No
End
End
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use a cursor to do this:

create function [dbo].f_teste_loop
returns @tabela table
(
    cod  int,
    nome varchar(10)
)
as 
begin

```
insert into @tabela values (1, 'verde');
insert into @tabela values (2, 'amarelo');
insert into @tabela values (3, 'azul');
insert into @tabela values (4, 'branco');

return;
```

end

create procedure [dbo].[sp_teste_loop]
as
begin

```
DECLARE @cod int, @nome varchar(10);

DECLARE curLoop CURSOR STATIC LOCAL 
FOR
SELECT  
    cod
   ,nome
FROM 
    dbo.f_teste_loop();

OPEN curLoop;

FETCH NEXT FROM curLoop
           INTO @cod, @nome;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT @nome;

    FETCH NEXT FROM curLoop
           INTO @cod, @nome;
END

CLOSE curLoop;
DEALLOCATE curLoop;
```

end

Comment: Wasn't the original question "Without using a cursor"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to provide the set-based solution.

```
insert  @databases (DatabaseID, Name, Server)
select DatabaseID, Name, Server 
From ... (Use whatever query you would have used in the loop or cursor)
```

This is far faster than any looping techique and is easier to write and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using the Offset Fetch if you have a unique ID you can sort your table by:

```
DECLARE @TableVariable (ID int, Name varchar(50));
DECLARE @RecordCount int;
SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM @TableVariable;

WHILE @RecordCount > 0
BEGIN
SELECT ID, Name FROM @TableVariable ORDER BY ID OFFSET @RecordCount - 1 FETCH NEXT 1 ROW;
SET @RecordCount = @RecordCount - 1;
END
```

This way I don't need to add fields to the table or use a window function.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous post that set-based operations will typically perform better, but if you do need to iterate over the rows here's the approach I would take:

1. Add a new field to your table variable (Data Type Bit, default 0)
2. Insert your data
3. Select the Top 1 Row where fUsed = 0 *(Note: fUsed is the name of the field in step 1)*
4. Perform whatever processing you need to do
5. Update the record in your table variable by setting fUsed = 1 for the record
6. Select the next unused record from the table and repeat the process

   ```
   DECLARE @databases TABLE  
   (  
       DatabaseID  int,  
       Name        varchar(15),     
       Server      varchar(15),   
       fUsed       BIT DEFAULT 0  
   ) 

   -- insert a bunch rows into @databases

   DECLARE @DBID INT

   SELECT TOP 1 @DBID = DatabaseID from @databases where fUsed = 0 

   WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 and @DBID IS NOT NULL  
   BEGIN  
       -- Perform your processing here  

       --Update the record to "used" 

       UPDATE @databases SET fUsed = 1 WHERE DatabaseID = @DBID  

       --Get the next record  
       SELECT TOP 1 @DBID = DatabaseID from @databases where fUsed = 0   
   END
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Step1: Below select statement creates a temp table with unique row number for each record.

```
select eno,ename,eaddress,mobno int,row_number() over(order by eno desc) as rno into #tmp_sri from emp
```

Step2:Declare required variables

```
DECLARE @ROWNUMBER INT
DECLARE @ename varchar(100)
```

Step3: Take total rows count from temp table

```
SELECT @ROWNUMBER = COUNT(*) FROM #tmp_sri
declare @rno int
```

Step4: Loop temp table based on unique row number create in temp

```
while @rownumber>0
begin
  set @rno=@rownumber
  select @ename=ename from #tmp_sri where rno=@rno  **// You can take columns data from here as many as you want**
  set @rownumber=@rownumber-1
  print @ename **// instead of printing, you can write insert, update, delete statements**
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach only requires one variable and does not delete any rows from @databases.  I know there are a lot of answers here, but I don't see one that uses MIN to get your next ID like this.

```
DECLARE @databases TABLE
(
    DatabaseID    int,
    Name        varchar(15),   
    Server      varchar(15)
)

-- insert a bunch rows into @databases

DECLARE @CurrID INT

SELECT @CurrID = MIN(DatabaseID)
FROM @databases

WHILE @CurrID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    -- Do stuff for @CurrID

    SELECT @CurrID = MIN(DatabaseID)
    FROM @databases
    WHERE DatabaseID > @CurrID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, which makes use of an infinite loop, the `BREAK` statement, and the `@@ROWCOUNT` function.   No cursors or temporary table are necessary, and I only need to write one query to get the next row in the `@databases` table:

```
declare @databases table
(
    DatabaseID    int,
    [Name]        varchar(15),   
    [Server]      varchar(15)
);


-- Populate the [@databases] table with test data.
insert into @databases (DatabaseID, [Name], [Server])
select X.DatabaseID, X.[Name], X.[Server]
from (values 
    (1, 'Roger', 'ServerA'),
    (5, 'Suzy', 'ServerB'),
    (8675309, 'Jenny', 'TommyTutone')
) X (DatabaseID, [Name], [Server])


-- Create an infinite loop & ensure that a break condition is reached in the loop code.
declare @databaseId int;

while (1=1)
begin
    -- Get the next database ID.
    select top(1) @databaseId = DatabaseId 
    from @databases 
    where DatabaseId > isnull(@databaseId, 0);

    -- If no rows were found by the preceding SQL query, you're done; exit the WHILE loop.
    if (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) break;

    -- Otherwise, do whatever you need to do with the current [@databases] table row here.
    print 'Processing @databaseId #' + cast(@databaseId as varchar(50));
end
```

Comment: I just realized that **@ControlFreak** recommended this approach before me; I simply added comments and a more verbose example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I am using 2008 R2. This code that I am using is to build indexes on key fields (SSNO & EMPR_NO) n all tales

```
if object_ID('tempdb..#a')is not NULL drop table #a

select 'IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysindexes WHERE name ='+CHAR(39)+''+'IDX_'+COLUMN_NAME+'_'+SUBSTRING(table_name,5,len(table_name)-3)+char(39)+')' 
+' begin DROP INDEX [IDX_'+COLUMN_NAME+'_'+SUBSTRING(table_name,5,len(table_name)-3)+'] ON '+table_schema+'.'+table_name+' END Create index IDX_'+COLUMN_NAME+'_'+SUBSTRING(table_name,5,len(table_name)-3)+ ' on '+ table_schema+'.'+table_name+' ('+COLUMN_NAME+') '   'Field'
,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by table_NAMe) as  'ROWNMBR'
into #a
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where (COLUMN_NAME like '%_SSNO_%' or COLUMN_NAME like'%_EMPR_NO_')
    and TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

declare @loopcntr int
declare @ROW int
declare @String nvarchar(1000)
set @loopcntr=(select count(*)  from #a)
set @ROW=1  

while (@ROW <= @loopcntr)
    begin
        select top 1 @String=a.Field 
        from #A a
        where a.ROWNMBR = @ROW
        execute sp_executesql @String
        set @ROW = @ROW + 1
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @pk = @pk + 1
```

would be better:

```
SET @pk += @pk
```

Avoid using SELECT if you are not referencing tables are are just assigning values.