# Find non-ASCII characters in varchar columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, non-ascii-characters

How can rows with non-ASCII characters be returned using SQL Server?
If you can show how to do it for one column would be great.

I am doing something like this now, but it is not working

```
select *
from Staging.APARMRE1 as ar
where ar.Line like '%[^!-~ ]%'
```

**For extra credit,** if it can span *all* `varchar` columns in a table, that would be outstanding! In this solution, it would be nice to return three columns:

- The identity field for that record. (This will allow the whole record to be reviewed with another query.)
- The column name
- The text with the invalid character

```
 Id | FieldName | InvalidText       |
----+-----------+-------------------+
 25 | LastName  | Solís             |
 56 | FirstName | François          |
100 | Address1  | 123 Ümlaut street |
```

Invalid characters would be any outside the range of SPACE (32<sub>10</sub>) through `~` (127<sub>10</sub>)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683496/475876

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try something like this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (PK int, col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20), col3 varchar(20));
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1, 'ok','ok','ok');
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2, 'BA'+char(182)+'D','ok','ok');
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3, 'ok',char(182)+'BAD','ok');
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (4, 'ok','ok','B'+char(182)+'AD');
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (5, char(182)+'BAD','ok',char(182)+'BAD');
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (6, 'BAD'+char(182),'B'+char(182)+'AD','BAD'+char(182)+char(182)+char(182));

--if you have a Numbers table use that, other wise make one using a CTE
WITH AllNumbers AS
(   SELECT 1 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<1000
)
SELECT 
    pk, 'Col1' BadValueColumn, CONVERT(varchar(20),col1) AS BadValue --make the XYZ in convert(varchar(XYZ), ...) the largest value of col1, col2, col3
    FROM @YourTable           y
        INNER JOIN AllNumbers n ON n.Number <= LEN(y.col1)
    WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col1, n.Number, 1))<32 OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col1, n.Number, 1))>127
UNION
SELECT 
    pk, 'Col2' BadValueColumn, CONVERT(varchar(20),col2) AS BadValue --make the XYZ in convert(varchar(XYZ), ...) the largest value of col1, col2, col3
    FROM @YourTable           y
        INNER JOIN AllNumbers n ON n.Number <= LEN(y.col2)
    WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col2, n.Number, 1))<32 OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col2, n.Number, 1))>127
UNION
SELECT 
    pk, 'Col3' BadValueColumn, CONVERT(varchar(20),col3) AS BadValue --make the XYZ in convert(varchar(XYZ), ...) the largest value of col1, col2, col3
    FROM @YourTable           y
        INNER JOIN AllNumbers n ON n.Number <= LEN(y.col3)
    WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col3, n.Number, 1))<32 OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(y.col3, n.Number, 1))>127
order by 1
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```

OUTPUT:

```
pk          BadValueColumn BadValue
----------- -------------- --------------------
2           Col1           BA¶D
3           Col2           ¶BAD
4           Col3           B¶AD
5           Col1           ¶BAD
5           Col3           ¶BAD
6           Col1           BAD¶
6           Col2           B¶AD
6           Col3           BAD¶¶¶

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Interesting approach KM. For my own curiousity...can I ask why the line "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) " at the end of your statement is needed and what it will do in this case?

Comment: "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)" is necessary for the CTE, which recursively builds a set of rows from 1 to 1000, the default value is 100 (I think) any nested recursion calls in a cte to exceed the default requires this option to be set.  If you had a numbers table http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/65223 you would not need the CTE or this "OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)" line

Answer (score 116):

Here is a solution for the single column search using PATINDEX.
It also displays the StartPosition, InvalidCharacter and ASCII code.

```
select line,
  patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,Line) as [Position],
  substring(line,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,Line),1) as [InvalidCharacter],
  ascii(substring(line,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,Line),1)) as [ASCIICode]
from  staging.APARMRE1
where patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,Line) >0
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Would you explain how this works?

Comment: Gerhard is providing a regular expression to the PATINDEX function. The regex is [^ !-~]. I'm not sure why he includes the exclamation character in there since it is right after the space character numerically. The point is that the regex finds things that are characters not in the range of Space-Tilde (32-126).

Comment: It's worth noting that the PATINDEX function doesn't accept any regular expression pattern. It's has it's own syntax which is similar to regular expressions in some respects.

Comment: ASCII printable characters are from char code 32 to 126. This is saying find anything that is not a space (Char(32)) or any characters from the range of ! [Char(33)] to ~ [Char(126)], which is the entire printable ASCII range.  The square brackets mean match a character in a range, and the ^ after the opening bracket means not in this range.

Answer (score 30):

I've been running this bit of code with success

```
declare @UnicodeData table (
     data nvarchar(500)
)
insert into 
    @UnicodeData
values 
    (N'Horse�')
    ,(N'Dog')
    ,(N'Cat')

select
    data
from
    @UnicodeData 
where
    data collate LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN != cast(data as varchar(max))
```

Which works well for known columns.

For extra credit, I wrote this quick script to search all nvarchar columns in a given table for Unicode characters.

```
declare 
    @sql    varchar(max)    = ''
    ,@table sysname         = 'mytable' -- enter your table here

;with ColumnData as (
    select
        RowId               = row_number() over (order by c.COLUMN_NAME)
        ,c.COLUMN_NAME
        ,ColumnName         = '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
        ,TableName          = '[' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + ']' 
    from
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where
        c.DATA_TYPE         = 'nvarchar'
        and c.TABLE_NAME    = @table
)
select
    @sql = @sql + 'select FieldName = ''' + c.ColumnName + ''',         InvalidCharacter = [' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ']  from ' + c.TableName + ' where ' + c.ColumnName + ' collate LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN != cast(' + c.ColumnName + ' as varchar(max)) '  +  case when c.RowId <> (select max(RowId) from ColumnData) then  ' union all ' else '' end + char(13)
from
    ColumnData c

-- check
-- print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

I'm not a fan of dynamic SQL but it does have its uses for exploratory queries like this.

Comment: While I sometimes edit answers to include semicolons that have been left off, it wouldn't be right to do so here as it the answer would no longer be accurate as to the code you're using.  But it's important not to leave them off.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server#answer-26356175

Answer (score 16):

This script searches for non-ascii characters in one column.  It generates a string of all valid characters, here code point 32 to 127.  Then it searches for rows that don't match the list:

```
declare @str varchar(128);
declare @i int;
set @str = '';
set @i = 32;
while @i <= 127
    begin
    set @str = @str + '|' + char(@i);
    set @i = @i + 1;
    end;

select  col1
from    YourTable
where   col1 like '%[^' + @str + ']%' escape '|';
```

Comment: This works with one minor change Varchar(128) needs to be bigger because 2 characters are being stored. I made it Varchar(200). It does take some time to run through my database. I am also suprised that a range cannot be used to simplified this process. i.e. like '%[^| -|~]%' escape '|' I tried to get a range working but it does not return the correct information.

Comment: I also changed 127 to 126. I did not want the DEL character.

Answer (score 10):

running the various solutions on some real world data - 12M rows varchar length ~30, around 9k dodgy rows, no full text index in play, the patIndex solution is the fastest, and it also selects the most rows.

(pre-ran km. to set the cache to a known state, ran the 3 processes, and finally ran km again - the last 2 runs of km gave times within 2 seconds)

patindex solution by Gerhard Weiss -- Runtime 0:38, returns 9144 rows

```
select dodgyColumn from myTable fcc
WHERE  patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,dodgyColumn ) >0
```

the substring-numbers solution by MT. -- Runtime 1:16, returned 8996 rows

```
select dodgyColumn from myTable fcc
INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers32k dn ON dn.number<(len(fcc.dodgyColumn ))
WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(fcc.dodgyColumn , dn.Number, 1))<32 
    OR ASCII(SUBSTRING(fcc.dodgyColumn , dn.Number, 1))>127
```

udf solution by Deon Robertson -- Runtime 3:47, returns 7316 rows

```
select dodgyColumn 
from myTable 
where dbo.udf_test_ContainsNonASCIIChars(dodgyColumn , 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a user defined function available on the web 'Parse Alphanumeric'.  Google UDF parse alphanumeric and you should find the code for it.  This user defined function removes all characters that doesn't fit between 0-9, a-z, and A-Z.

```
Select * from Staging.APARMRE1 ar
where udf_parsealpha(ar.last_name) <> ar.last_name
```

That should bring back any records that have a last_name with invalid chars for you...though your bonus points question is a bit more of a challenge, but I think a case statement could handle it.  This is a bit psuedo code, I'm not entirely sure if it'd work.

```
Select id, case when udf_parsealpha(ar.last_name) <> ar.last_name then 'last name'
when udf_parsealpha(ar.first_name) <> ar.first_name then 'first name'
when udf_parsealpha(ar.Address1) <> ar.last_name then 'Address1'
end, 
case when udf_parsealpha(ar.last_name) <> ar.last_name then ar.last_name
when udf_parsealpha(ar.first_name) <> ar.first_name then ar.first_name
when udf_parsealpha(ar.Address1) <> ar.last_name then ar.Address1
end
from Staging.APARMRE1 ar
where udf_parsealpha(ar.last_name) <> ar.last_name or
udf_parsealpha(ar.first_name) <> ar.first_name or
udf_parsealpha(ar.Address1) <> ar.last_name
```

I wrote this in the forum post box...so I'm not quite sure if that'll function as is, but it should be close.  I'm not quite sure how it will behave if a single record has two fields with invalid chars either.

As an alternative, you should be able to change the from clause away from a single table and into a subquery that looks something like:

```
select id,fieldname,value from (
Select id,'last_name' as 'fieldname', last_name as 'value'
from Staging.APARMRE1 ar
Union
Select id,'first_name' as 'fieldname', first_name as 'value'
from Staging.APARMRE1 ar
---(and repeat unions for each field)
)
where udf_parsealpha(value) <> value
```

Benefit here is for every column you'll only need to extend the union statement here, while you need to put that comparisson three times for every column in the case statement version of this script

Comment: Comment on myself...the case statement version, I mentioned a single row having multiple columns with bad values. If both first_name and last_name had a bad value in it...I think the case statement will find the first_name portion and show it correctly, but would end there and not show the last_name value correctly. Probably not an optimal solution....the subquery version at the bottom of my post that unions all the tables values into id,columnname,value format appears to be much more functional and easier to follow

Answer (score 3):

To find which field has invalid characters:

```
SELECT * FROM Staging.APARMRE1 FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
```

You can test it with this query:

```
SELECT top 1 'char 31: '+char(31)+' (hex 0x1F)' field
from sysobjects
FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
```

The result will be:

> Msg 6841, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 FOR XML could not serialize the
>   data for node 'field' because it contains a character (0x001F) which
>   is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it
>   to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64
>   directive.

It is very useful when you write xml files and get error of invalid characters when validate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a UDF I built to detectc columns with extended ascii charaters. It is quick and you can extended the character set you want to check. The second parameter allows you to switch between checking anything outside the standard character set or allowing an extended set:

```
create function [dbo].[udf_ContainsNonASCIIChars]
(
@string nvarchar(4000),
@checkExtendedCharset bit
)
returns bit
as
begin

    declare @pos int = 0;
    declare @char varchar(1);
    declare @return bit = 0;

    while @pos < len(@string)
    begin
        select @char = substring(@string, @pos, 1)
        if ascii(@char) < 32 or ascii(@char) > 126 
            begin
                if @checkExtendedCharset = 1
                    begin
                        if ascii(@char) not in (9,124,130,138,142,146,150,154,158,160,170,176,180,181,183,184,185,186,192,193,194,195,196,197,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,209,210,211,212,213,214,216,217,218,219,220,221,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255)
                            begin
                                select @return = 1;
                                select @pos = (len(@string) + 1)
                            end
                        else
                            begin
                                select @pos = @pos + 1
                            end
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        select @return = 1;
                        select @pos = (len(@string) + 1)    
                    end
            end
        else
            begin
                select @pos = @pos + 1
            end
    end

    return @return;

end
```

USAGE:

```
select Address1 
from PropertyFile_English
where udf_ContainsNonASCIIChars(Address1, 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I took Gerhard Weiss's script and made it my own as my business scenario was pretty simple and only needed to update 10K rows.

```
--CONTAINS() function requires a full text catalog
--interesting to me is that CONTAINS() can find the ASCII characters, but REPLACE() cannot
WITH cte_AsciiCharacterList AS
(select LineID
    , LineSyntax
    , Position = patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax)
    , InvalidCharacter = substring(LineSyntax,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax),1)
    , ASCIICode = ascii(substring(LineSyntax,patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax),1))
    , LineSyntaxPart1 = SUBSTRING(LineSyntax, 1, patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax) - 1)
    , LineSyntaxPart2 = SUBSTRING(LineSyntax, patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax) + 3, 10000)
    , NewLineSyntax =  SUBSTRING(LineSyntax, 1, patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax) - 1) + '-' + SUBSTRING(LineSyntax, patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,LineSyntax) + 3, 10000)
FROM stg.TableName
WHERE Contains(linesyntax, '"ΓÇö"')
)
UPDATE stg.TableName
SET LineSyntax = NewLineSyntax
FROM stg.TableName x
INNER JOIN cte_AsciiCharacterList y on x.LineID = y.LineID
```