# How to check a string is in a specific format in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

Need to find solution in SQL to check wether a string  is in format

```
aCODE_1111111111
```

`a` - lower case letter
`CODE` - Uppercase letter.
Format start with `aCODE_` and followed by 10 numbers. `aCODE_` should be constant.

IF the input is in `aCODE_1234567890` , result is true
IF the input is in `aCODE_2256784558` , result is true
IF the input is in `ACODE_1234567890` , result is false
IF the input is in `aCODe_1234567890` , result is false
IF the input is in `aCODE_123456789`  , result is false

Comment: What if you have 11 digits instead of 10? should that result with `true` or `false`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 11 digits will result in False

Comment: Can that format be a part of the string? I mean, with `This is aCODE_0123456789 and it should be fine` - the result should be `true` or `false`?

Comment: @404 string should only start with "aCODE_"

Comment: @ZoharPeled No it cannot be a part of string. This is aCODE_0123456789 and it should be fine , will result as False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your request, your query should be like this :

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN t.solution SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
                like 'aCODE[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
           END as solution, *
    FROM yourtable
```

Comment: This might not be a case sensitive comparison. Use `collate` to make sure it is.

Comment: @VishnuDev you should use collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS to make it case sensitive.

Comment: But if I am passing this string as a parameter , then collate cannot be used.

Comment: @VishnuDev you can declare it from the begining, check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096720/collate-declared-sql-variable

Comment: underscore must be escaped

Comment: `aCODE_1234567890` will fail this test (even though it should pass) because it's last digit is `0`. Also, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is the wrong collation as it's case insensitive. it should be `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` The correct condition is `Col collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
                like 'aCODE[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi your answer is correct just change last expression by `[0-9]`. Votes is not important. correct answer will be upper side always :)