# How can I tell if a column can be made into a varChar from a nVarChar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to determine if a column contains any non-ASCII data such that I can't convert it from nVarChar to varChar.

Ideally I would like to do this in T-SQL.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167489/detect-if-any-values-in-nvarchar-columns-are-actually-unicode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891331/find-non-ascii-characters-in-varchar-columns-using-sql-server

Comment: "non-ASCII" seems overly specific. Are you going for a test that doesn't depend on the varChar collocation? If not, @Pரதீப் 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48363762/2226988) would work for the database collation, allowing whichever non-ASCII characters it supports. (SQL Server doesn't have a collation with ASCII as the character set.)

Comment: What I am really looking for is to answer the question "Does this column need to be nVarChar or could I change it to nVarChar without losing data?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find non-ASCII characters in varchar columns using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891331/find-non-ascii-characters-in-varchar-columns-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other current answer is missing a step. All it checks is that after converting to `varchar` they still compare equal - not that they are actually the same character.

The string `N'⁴＂＊８？'` would silently be converted to `'4"*8?'` and still compare equal under many collations.

See

```
SELECT nvarcharcolumn,
       CAST(nvarcharcolumn AS VARCHAR(4000))
FROM   ( VALUES(N'⁴＂＊８？')) V(nvarcharcolumn )
WHERE  nvarcharcolumn <> cast(nvarcharcolumn AS VARCHAR(4000))
```

I would check that it round trips to the exact same value after casting to varchar and back again.You can do this with

```
WHERE nvarcharcolumn <> cast(nvarcharcolumn as varchar(4000)) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN
```

Answer (score 8):

one simple way is by converting to `varchar`

```
select * 
from yourtable 
where nvarcharcolumn <> cast(nvarcharcolumn as varchar(8000))
```

Comment: This isn't really reliable, see these problem characters that will get silently converted to close equivalents. http://rextester.com/HMFC61426

Comment: So you can add a `collate Latin1_General_BIN` to see if it round trips correctly as the varchar will already be implicitly cast back to nvarchar for the comparison.

Comment: @MartinSmith, could show a example of using `collate Latin1_General_BIN`?

Comment: `WHERE nvarcharcolumn <> cast(nvarcharcolumn as varchar(8000))    collate Latin1_General_BIN`

Comment: @MartinSmith Never thought about that. Thanks Martin for opening my eyes yet again ;)