# Can't remove Trailing spaces in the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column with data like:

```
'2020193'
'3208391'
'1038291'
'9349203'
```

The data type is `varchar` and I can't change it to `int` (data managed in this datatype always).

I have some rows with trailing spaces like:

```
' 2222928'
' 3213331'
```

I need to remove that trailing space from start. I have tried `SUBSTRING()` or `TRIM()/RTRIM()/LTRIM()`, but didn't worked any of those.

```
select (rtrim(ltrim(doc_id))) from bpm.sales where len(doc_id) = 8
select left(doc_id,2) from bpm.sales where len(doc_id) = 8
select charindex(' ',doc_id) from bpm.sales where len(doc_id) = 8
```

Also, when I am trying to search the data like:

```
select doc_id from bpm.sales where doc_id = ' 2269203'
```

I am geting nothing where it exist in the column. With `CHARINDEX()` I got `0`.

Can someone explain me this behaviour and suggest a solution?

Comment: Looks more like leading spaces.

Comment: Are you sure it's a space? Could it be a tab or some other invisible character?

Comment: Run this query to identify the problem rows: 
SELECT doc_id
FROM bpm.sales
WHERE ISNUMERIC(doc_Id) = 0

Comment: I think the only thing we're sure of is that it's _not_ a space. It's some other non-printing character. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917698/5790584

Comment: What is the result of those SELECT statements? They don't change values (you need UPDATE for that), just report on existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of everything up to the first character you do want:

```
select stuff(doc_id, 1, patindex('%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%', doc_id) - 1, '')
```