# In SQL Server, how can I check if a field contains a character outside of a specific range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that will check if a single character within an nvarchar field is outside of a valid range.

I thought a query like this would work, but the results include both rows instead of only the invalid one:

```
select foo
from (
    select N'ABDC' as foo
    union all 
    select N'ABǼC' as foo
) as bar
where bar.foo like '%[^ -~]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

The valid range is anything within ASCII space and the tilde.

A simpler example is also failing:

```
select foo
from (
    select N'ABDC' as foo
    union all 
    select N'ABzC' as foo
) as bar
where bar.foo like '%[^A-Z]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

This returns no results while this returns the correct row:

```
select foo
from (
    select N'ABDC' as foo
    union all 
    select N'AB~C' as foo
) as bar
where bar.foo like '%[^A-Z]%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

Here's a fiddle of the simple example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/93202

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work using LIKE based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917698/98757):

```
select foo
from (
    select N'ABDC' as foo
    union all 
    select N'ABǼC' as foo
) as bar
where bar.foo COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN like N'%[^ -~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Looks like I just needed a different collation.

Similarly, this works as well:

```
select foo
from (
    select N'ABDC' as foo
    union all 
    select N'ABǼC' as foo
) as bar
where patindex('%[^ -~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,bar.foo) > 0
```