# Get nvarchar records that were inserted as varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, nvarchar

How can I get all values of an `NVARCHAR` column whose some of the values were accidently inserted without using the `N` prefix and so was replaced with `?`, and then change those values into the correct form?

For example, if I have the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    Value nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #Test(Value) values(N'иытание1')
INSERT INTO #Test(Value) values('иытание2')
INSERT INTO #Test(Value) values(N'иытание3')

SELECT * FROM #Test
```

Output:

```
Value 
-------
иытание1
????????2 
иытание3
```

I want to get what was originally `'иытание2'` and later turned into gibberish, and fix it.

Comment: You cannot. The `?` is not a placeholder; it's the actual replacement character used when the string was originally converted (to the database default collation, before it got stored in the column). You can see this more clearly with `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Value) FROM #Test`; the `3F00` are the codepoints for `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, because it was *converted* to `?` on insertion into the table. The original data is gone. A literal string is created as a `VARCHAR` unless you prefix it with `N`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below query to find out the rows, which have just ASCII characters.

[Reference SO post on finding non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891331/find-non-ascii-characters-in-varchar-columns-using-sql-server)

```sql
-- > 0 means NON-ASCII characters are present
-- = 0 means only ASCII characters are present
SELECT * FROM #TEST 
WHERE
patindex('%[^ !-~]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN,VALUE) = 0
```

> ????????2