# Searching for special chars in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

```
select * 
from table
where column LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

How can I include that the following characters are also considered not to be "special" on the where clause?

```
(,./;#:[]{}=-_+)(*^!`\|)
```

Basically I'd like to return bunch of cyrillic/nordic chars or any other funny characters.

Also what's the difference between 
    select * 
    from table
    where column LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'

and

```
select * 
from table
where column NOT LIKE '%[0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

To Re-iterate: I'd like to find something like this **DÃƒÂº**
instead of **Dafao**.

Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (Some of them have regexp like, other don't.)

Comment: Have you tried the way I have posted?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it recognizes the funny Cyrillic characters to be within the range bracket of a-z and A-Z. Is this something to do with the collation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend your like with OR concondition..

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
     OR column LIKE "%#%" 
     OR column LIKE "%{%" OR (etc.)
```

Comment: OR operator or AND?

Comment: OR .. You have to get the values against any of these special characters..

Comment: right.. I dont want to receive values towards those special chars. I want to get cyrillic values like ÃƒÂº with a different text format.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply include those characters in the same pattern you have already, just make sure to escape each of them with "\" where necessary, like this:

```
select * 
from table
where column LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z\,\.\/\;\#\:\[\]\{\}\=\-\_\+\)\(\*\^\!\`\\\|]%'
```

**EDIT:**

To better accommodate Unicode (i.e. the `nvarchar` data type), there are several options discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686967/how-can-i-find-unicode-non-ascii-characters-in-an-ntext-field-in-a-sql-server-20), and one of the more elegant (IIF your default collation is ASCII or similar) seems to be to use a condition like this:

```
select *
from table
where column <> cast(column as varchar(500)) --length should match the base column length
or column LIKE N'%[^0-9a-zA-Z\,\.\/\;\#\:\[\]\{\}\=\-\_\+\)\(\*\^\!\`\\\|]%'
```

The comparison of the nvarchar value with the varchar equivalent is an easy way to identify all non-ascii-compatible characters (like Cyrillic), and then the LIKE filters further down to a subset of ASCII chars.  Seems to work quite well for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it doesn't return any Cyrillic or funny looking characters. Perhaps it is to do with the collation since it is recognizing them to be between a-z and A-Z?

Comment: @DiamondDog the answer is now edited to better handle non-ascii (Unicode) content

Answer (score 0):

```
... LIKE '[[]%'
```

You can use `[ ]` to surround a special character (or range). You don't need to escape the closing bracket.