# SQL Server dump of varchar data to file loads in mysql but not mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb

I dumped a lot of string data from a SQL Server database into a text file as INSERTS on my Windows10 workstation using the SQLCMD via the cygwin command line.

It loads into mysql fine, but in mariadb I get this error:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 384: 
    Incorrect string value: '\x87ao Su...' for column 'description' at row 1995
```

My SQL Server DB has these settings:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.collation_name 
FROM   sys.tables AS T 
       INNER JOIN sys.columns C 
               ON T.object_id = C.object_id 
WHERE  collation_name IS NOT NULL; 

collation_name: Latin1_General_CI_AS

SELECT DISTINCT C.collation_name 
FROM   sys.tables AS T 
       INNER JOIN sys.columns C 
               ON T.object_id = C.object_id 
WHERE  collation_name IS NOT NULL; 
collation_name: Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

and this is MySQL (where it inserts happily):

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM forecast
--------------

+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field              | Type             | Collation       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| description        | varchar(255)     | utf8_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL              |                | select,insert,update,references |         |

SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, @@collation_connection
--------------

+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database | @@collation_connection |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_unicode_ci      | utf8_general_ci        |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

and this is from MariaDB where it gives that error above:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM forecast
--------------

+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field              | Type             | Collation       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| description        | varchar(255)     | utf8_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL                |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------------------+------------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [tardis]> SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, @@collation_connection;
--------------
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database, @@collation_connection
--------------

+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database | @@collation_connection |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_unicode_ci      | utf8_general_ci        |
+--------------------------+----------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

As far as I can tell, MariaDB should behave the same as MySQL but it doesn't.

What do I have to do?

I could convert the text with a SQL Server function - at the moment I am just escaping \' characters - but how?

**[UPDATE]** Just discovered that MariaDB doesn't have any problems with the data when I run the import SQL commands from file.

It's only when I pipe it directly on the command line from SQLCMD to mysql.exe that I get the error:

```
$ SQLCMD.EXE -i "c:\dev\workspace\sql\generate-inserts-for-migration.sql" \
       -h-1 -S "myhost" -d MyDBName -r1 -W \
       -b -f o:65001 | mysql -h myhost.amazonaws.com -u adam -p
```

I wanted to do it like that so that I don't have to create a 10GB SQL file on my hard drive, or I could even run it in a docker container (with limited GB space) on the same network on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `sqlcmd` to convert your output text to unicode as you create your SQL file dump.

Try using the `-u` flag when you dump your file.

Or try using this flag when you import it, to translate from latin-1 to utf-8

```
 -f i:1252,o:65001
```

1252 is microsoft-speak for Latin-1 and 68001 for utf-8.

And, by the way, for futureproofing your MySQL / MariaDB data, you should consider using utf8mb4 as your character set rather than just utf8. Here's an explanation.  [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

Comment: `sqlcmd` is not playing ball. Neither `-u` nor `-f o:65001` changed the output into something mariadb could handle. I searched through the dumped file and couldn't find `\x87ao` or anything like it. Is it possible that it worked for mysql because I saved the dump to file with `> dump.sql` but this time for mariadb I'm just doing `SQLCMD | mysql` on the command line? I figured not writing the file would save hours.

Comment: `\x87` is potentially the character `‡` in Latin1.

Comment: in Latin1, C-cedilla is \xC7, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 . You data is probably in cp850, which is default OEM charset for Western Europe. C-cedill is \x87 there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

Answer (score 0):

The special character turned out to be C with a cedilla as in `Curaçao`

which looked like this in the dumped file

```
 Cura<87>ao
```

after exporting it from SQL Server with `SQLCMD -f o:65001` where 65001 is the Microsoft UTF8 code page.

I also tried `SQLCMD -f o:1252` since the database says it's `latin1`.

I discovered what the special character was thanks to this excellent answer [How can I find Unicode/non-ASCII characters in an NTEXT field in a SQL Server 2005 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686967/how-can-i-find-unicode-non-ascii-characters-in-an-ntext-field-in-a-sql-server-20#answer-687037)

and I assume that mySQL (as opposed to MariaDB) was simply importing it badly without complaint.

The [MariaDB docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/) told me to set the `--default-character-set` on the command line appropriately, so I tried `latin1` and `utf8`, neither of which worked.

I then looked at the long list of character sets for MariaDB in `/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml` and it turns out the `cp1250` works without complaint but it imports the special character as `‡`

The command was `mysql --default-character-set=cp1250`.

I haven't been able to import the data correctly, but at least I've got it to import in MariaDB now.

Comment: Or use `SET NAMES latin1` after connecting.  This declares that the client encoding is latin1.  (This can differ from the table declarations; conversion is automatic.)