# What is an alternative to cursors for sql looping?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, database-cursor

Using SQL 2005 / 2008

I have to use a forward cursor, but I don't want to suffer poor performance. Is there a faster way I can loop without using cursors?

Comment: It entirely depends on what you are trying to do! Perhaps give us a hint, so we can give you an answer that will make sense to your situation?

Comment: Its not me, My Manager doesnt want me to use Cursors. Eventually i am looking to replace cursor for looping ..!

Comment: I am talking about the specific task that you think you need cursors for. Explain what that is and a helpful answer may be given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a `WHILE` loop, however you should seek to achieve a more set based operation as anything in SQL that is iterative is subject to performance issues.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx

Comment: I think @Dustin is saying that if you can do this using set-based operations, the looping might be entirely unnecessary.

Comment: and @DavE, you both might be right. What exactly you are trying to explain by Set Operators? I am sure that Recursive queries can do it ..!

Comment: @Chok - You are 100% correct that a `WHILE` loop is an integral part of a `CURSOR`. However, I have seen `WHILE` loops perform better that a `CURSOR` as a cursor has a lot of options that can hinder performance. I believe a `FAST FORWARD` `CURSOR` should be similar to a regular `WHILE` loop.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the example using cursor:

```
DECLARE @VisitorID int
DECLARE @FirstName varchar(30), @LastName varchar(30)
-- declare cursor called ActiveVisitorCursor 
DECLARE ActiveVisitorCursor Cursor FOR
SELECT VisitorID, FirstName, LastName 
FROM Visitors
WHERE Active = 1
-- Open the cursor
OPEN ActiveVisitorCursor 
-- Fetch the first row of the cursor and assign its values into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM ActiveVisitorCursor INTO @VisitorID, @FirstName, @LastName 
-- perform action whilst a row was found
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 Exec MyCallingStoredProc @VisitorID, @Forename, @Surname
 -- get next row of cursor
 FETCH NEXT FROM ActiveVisitorCursor INTO @VisitorID, @FirstName, @LastName 
END
 -- Close the cursor to release locks
CLOSE ActiveVisitorCursor 
 -- Free memory used by cursor
DEALLOCATE ActiveVisitorCursor
```

Now here is the example how can we get same result without using cursor:

```
/* Here is alternative approach */

-- Create a temporary table, note the IDENTITY
-- column that will be used to loop through
-- the rows of this table
CREATE TABLE #ActiveVisitors (
       RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1), 
       VisitorID int,
       FirstName varchar(30),
       LastName varchar(30)
 )
DECLARE @NumberRecords int, @RowCounter int
DECLARE @VisitorID int, @FirstName varchar(30), @LastName varchar(30)

-- Insert the resultset we want to loop through
-- into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #ActiveVisitors (VisitorID, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT VisitorID, FirstName, LastName
FROM Visitors
WHERE Active = 1 

-- Get the number of records in the temporary table
SET @NumberRecords = @@RowCount 
--You can use: SET @NumberRecords = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #ActiveVisitors
SET @RowCounter = 1

-- loop through all records in the temporary table
-- using the WHILE loop construct
WHILE @RowCounter <= @NumberRecords
BEGIN
 SELECT @VisitorID = VisitorID, @FirstName = FirstName, @LastName = LastName 
 FROM #ActiveVisitors
 WHERE RowID = @RowCounter

 EXEC MyCallingStoredProc @VisitorID, @FirstName, @LastName

 SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1
END

-- drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #ActiveVisitors
```

Answer (score 10):

"NEVER use Cursors" is a wonderful example of how damaging simple rules can be. Yes, they are easy to communicate, but when we remove the reason for the rule so that we can have an "easy to follow" rule, then most people will just blindly follow the rule without thinking about it, even if following the rule has a negative impact.

Cursors, at least in SQL Server / T-SQL, are *greatly* misunderstood. It is not accurate to say "Cursors affect performance of SQL". They certainly have a tendency to, but a lot of that has to do with how people use them. When used properly, Cursors are faster, more efficient, and less error-prone than `WHILE` loops (yes, this is true and has been proven over and over again, regardless of who argues "cursors are evil").

First option is to try to find a set-based approach to the problem.

If logically there is no set-based approach (e.g. needing to call `EXEC` per each row), and the query for the Cursor is hitting real (non-Temp) Tables, then use the `STATIC` keyword which will put the results of the `SELECT` statement into an internal Temporary Table, and hence will not lock the base-tables of the query as you iterate through the results. By default, Cursors are "sensitive" to changes in the underlying Tables of the query and will verify that those records still exist as you call `FETCH NEXT` (hence a large part of why Cursors are often viewed as being slow). Using `STATIC` will not help if you need to be sensitive of records that might disappear while processing the result set, but that is a moot point if you are considering converting to a `WHILE` loop against a Temp Table (since that will also not know of changes to underlying data).

If the query for the cursor is only selecting from temporary tables and/or table variables, then you don't need to prevent locking as you don't have concurrency issues in those cases, in which case you should use `FAST_FORWARD` instead of `STATIC`.

I think it also helps to specify the three options of `LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY`, unless you specifically need a cursor that is not one or more of those. But I have not tested them to see if they improve performance.

Assuming that the operation is not eligible for being made set-based, then the following options are a good starting point for most operations:

```sql
DECLARE [Thing1] CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR SELECT columns
    FROM   Schema.ReadTable(s);


DECLARE [Thing2] CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT columns
    FROM   #TempTable(s) and/or @TableVariables;
```

Comment: http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/Avoiding-using-SQL-Cursors-20.aspx  - I found an article about replacing cursors by while loop .. ! As you /@Dave mentioned. Again, here we are creating a Temp Table ..!

Comment: I am not necessarily saying to create a temp table. I am saying that using the STATIC keyword will store the results of the Cursor query in a Temp Table automatically and hence not lock any of the tables in the query. It would be worth exploring this option of simply adding a single word "STATIC" to your code to see if you get the desired performance gain before re-engineering the code to have a WHILE loop.

Answer (score 4):

Common Table Expressions would be a good alternative as @Neil suggested.  Here's an example from Adventureworks:

```
WITH cte_PO AS 
(
SELECT [LineTotal]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderDetail]
),
minmax AS
(
    SELECT MIN([LineTotal]) as DayMin
        ,MAX([LineTotal]) as DayMax
        ,[ModifiedDate]
    FROM cte_PO
    GROUP BY [ModifiedDate]
)
SELECT * FROM minmax ORDER BY ModifiedDate
```

Here's the top few lines of what it returns:

```
DayMin     DayMax     ModifiedDate
135.36     8847.30    2001-05-24 00:00:00.000
129.8115   25334.925  2001-06-07 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 3):

[Recursive Queries using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).

Comment: Neil, Thank you ..! I believe you are right. Can you please some syntax as Sample.

Comment: There are examples on the link :o)

Comment: -1 Link-only answers are frowned upon since the external resource is not guaranteed to exist. Please copy relevant content from that link into this answer, and then I will remove the -1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to use a forward cursor, but I don't want to suffer poor performance. Is there a faster way I can loop without using cursors?

This depends on what you do with the cursor.

Almost everything can be rewritten using set-based operations in which case the loops are performed inside the query plan and since they involve no context switch are much faster.

However, there are some things `SQL Server` is just not good at, like computing cumulative values or joining on date ranges.

These kinds of queries can be made faster using a `CURSOR`:

- [**Flattening timespans: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/11/flattening-timespans-sql-server/)

But again, this is a quite a rare exception, and normally a set-based way performs better.

If you posted your query, we could probably optimize it and get rid of a `CURSOR`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want it for, you may be able to use a tally table.

Jeff Moden has an excellent article on tally tables [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a cursor, instead look for a set-based solution. If you can't find a set-based solution... still don't use a cursor! Post details of what you are trying to achieve, someone will be able to find a  set-based solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some scenarios where one can use [Tally tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_marks). It could be a good alternative of loop and cusrors but remember it cannot be applied in every case. A well explain case can be found [here](http://blogs.quovantis.com/sunil/2014/08/performance-gain-using-tally-tables-an-alternative-to-loops-and-cursors-in-sql/)

Comment: Well explained case - the link is dead