# Can't figure out why I'm getting an invalid column name error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have these two temp tables that I'm using (they were actually written by a previous developer and I'm trying to adapt his code to be faster without using cursors, but that's beside the point) and I've run into a little problem that I can't figure out.

Here's some code:

```
CREATE TABLE #bc1 (
         [ContractID] decimal
        ,[custid] int
        ,[PostDate] date
        ,[RouteID] varchar(50)
        ,[RouteCommission] money
        ,[ContractTotal] money
        ,[ContractTotal0] money
    )

    INSERT INTO #bc1 ( [ContractID], [custid], [PostDate], [RouteID], [RouteCommission] )
    SELECT
         t.[ContractID]
        ,t.[custid]
        ,t.[PostDate]
        ,t.[RouteID]
        ,t.[RouteCommission]
    FROM 
        #tc1 t;
```

Now, as you can see it's pretty simple. There's a table `#bc1` being created with five columns, and it gets all of the data from another table which has 7 columns. This is pretty much smack in the middle of the query (which is about four pages, which is why I didn't include it) and this is where it breaks.  It tells me

> *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 178
>
>   Invalid column name 'custid'.*

and it's driving me nuts.  Incidentally, line 178 is the insert statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the `#tc1` table has a `custid` field?

Comment: And does the table `#tc1` has a column `custid`?

Comment: The create statement is for #bc1, but the select expects the custid column in table #tc1

Comment: As a bonus comment (and because I lothe cursors), have a look here for alternatives ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425642/what-is-an-alternative-to-cursors-for-sql-looping

Comment: #tc1 does have a custid column.  I think the issue is the fact that the temp table was never dropped.  I dropped the temp table before creating it, we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Can you post the definition of #tc1? Also, sometimes the line number for an error can be off quite a bit. You could temporarily put an additional insert in the empty line that references a not existing table to see what line number you get for that. If that is not 177 your original error is somewhere else too.

Comment: I would use "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tc1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tc1"
and "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#bc1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #bc1" at the beginning of the query.

Comment: Are there any triggers or dynamic code that operate on the temp tables? If you're trying to get away from the cursors consider APPLY and CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Can you try 'SELECT * FROM #tc1' as a test (without inserting into #bc1 table).
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer