# Alternative to use cursors in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-cursor

It's not like that I am having trouble executing my cursors which are enclosed in a stored procedure. But I want to find more efficient way to achieve the same.

Here it goes.

Stored procedure : `RawFeed.sql` (runs every 5 minutes)

```
Set @GetATM = Cursor For
        Select DeviceCode,ReceivedOn
        From RawStatusFeed
        Where CRWR=2 AND Processed=0
        Order By ReceivedOn Desc
    Open @GetATM
    Fetch Next
    From @GetATM Into @ATM,@ReceivedOn
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
            Set @RawFeed=@ATM+' '+Convert(VarChar,@ReceivedOn,121)+' '+'002307'+' '+@ATM+' : Card Reader/Writer - FAULTY '
            Exec usp_pushRawDataAndProcess 1,@RawFeed
            Fetch Next
            From @GetATM Into @ATM,@ReceivedOn
        End
Set @GetATM = Cursor For
        Select DeviceCode,ReceivedOn
        From RawStatusFeed
        Where CRWR=0 AND Processed=0
        Order By ReceivedOn Desc
    Open @GetATM
    Fetch Next
    From @GetATM Into @ATM,@ReceivedOn
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        Begin
            Set @RawFeed=@ATM+' '+Convert(Varchar,@ReceivedOn,121)+' '+'002222'+' '+@ATM+' : Card Reader/Writer - OK '
            Exec usp_pushRawDataAndProcess 1,@RawFeed
            Fetch Next
            From @GetATM Into @ATM,@ReceivedOn
        End
```

Likewise I have 10 more `SET` statements which differ on `WHERE` condition parameter & string enclosed in `@RawFeed` variable.

For each row I get I execute another stored procedure on that particular row.

My question is

> *Is there any better way to achieve the same without using cursors?*

Variable @`RawFeed` Contains following `string` which is input to `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` stored procedure. now this will divide whole string and do some operation like `INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE` on some tables.

WE JUST CAN NOT PROCESS MORE THAN 1 STRING IN `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess`

```
NMAAO226 2012-09-22 16:10:06.123 002073 NMAAO226 : Journal Printer - OK 
WMUAO485 2012-09-22 16:10:06.123 002222 WMUAO485 : Card Reader/Writer - OK
```

Comment: Tautologically, any way that doesn't use cursors is better.

Comment: The answer rather depends on what `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` does. What does it do?

Comment: usp_pushRawDataAndProcess gets a long string it divide that string and depending on value present in that sub string it INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE records in few tables in DB.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: I suspect the answer depends on what happens in usp_pushRawDataAndProcess, and whether you could modify that for your specific purposes to process multiple entries rather than just 1 at a time. Meanwhile, you might get some perfomance improvements (and reduce the code a bit) if you use the cursor just once, including CRWR in your select, and doing some CASE statement based on the value of CRWR. But from where I'm sitting, I don't see a non-iterative solution.

Comment: SQL SERVER is 2008. Like CRWR There are Many Code With Diff. Values How can i use CASE there ? and usp_pushRawDataAndProcess Takes One String at a time only.It divides that string and process it.

Comment: For one, if you need a cursor, [use better cursor options than the defaults (e.g. `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`)](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server, like other relational databases, is desgined to, and is pretty good at, working on sets of data.

Databases are not good at procedural code where all the opportunities for optimization are obscured from the query processing engine.

Using `RawStatusFeed` to store some proprietry request string and then processing a list of those one by one, is going to be ineffiencnt for database code. This might make the inserts very fast for the client, and this might be very important, but it comes at a cost.

If you break the request string down on insert, or better still, before insert via a specialised SP call, then you can store the required changes in some intermediate relational model, rather than a list of strings. Then, every so often, you can process all the changes at once with one call to a stored procedure. Admittedly, it would probably make sense for that stored procedure to contain several query statements. However, with the right indexes and statistics the query processing engine will able to make an efficient execution plan for this new stored procedure.

The exact details of how this should be achieved depend on the exact details of the `RawStatusFeed` table and the implementation of `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess`. Although this seems like a rewrite, I don't imagine the `DeviceCode` column is that complicated.

---

So, the short answer is certainly yes but, I'd need to know what `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` does in detail.

The signature of the `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` SP is acting as a bottle neck.

---

If you can't change `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` and and won't create a set based alternative then you are stuck with the bottle neck.

So, rather than removing the bottle neck you could take another tack. Why not make more concurrent instances of the bottle neck to feed the data through.

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or above you could use some CLR to perform numerous instances of `usp_pushRawDataAndProcess` in parallel.

[Here is a link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29356/Asynchronous-T-SQL-Execution-Without-Service-Broke) to a project I used before to do something similar.

Comment: @SagarDumbre, the only edit I see says "WE JUST CAN NOT PROCESS MORE THAN 1 STRING", with that restriction in place I fear you will just be polishing a turd but, I've extended my answer with another alernative.

Answer (score 3):

I had always disliked cursors because of their slow performance. However, I found I didn't fully understand the different types of cursors and that in certain instances, cursors are a viable solution.

When you have a business problem that can only be solved by processing one row at a time, then a cursor is appropriate.

So to improve performance with the cursor, change the type of cursor you are using. Something I didn't know was, if you don't specify which type of cursor you are declaring, you get the Dynamic Optimistic type by default, which is the one that is the slowest for performance because it's doing lots of work under the hood. However, by declaring your cursor as a different type, say a static cursor, it has very good performance.

See these articles for a fuller explanation:

[The Truth About Cursors: Part I](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html)

[The Truth About Cursors: Part II](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-2.html)

[The Truth About Cursors: Part III](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-3.html)

I think the biggest con against cursors is performance, however, not laying out a task in a set based approach would probably rank second. Third would be readability and layout of the tasks as they usually don't have a lot of helpful comments.

The best alternative to a cursor I've found is to rework the logic to take a set based approach.

SQL Server is optimized to run the set based approach.  You write the query to return a result set of data, like a join on tables for example, but the SQL Server execution engine determines which join to use: Merge Join, Nested Loop Join, or Hash Join.  SQL Server determines the best possible joining algorithm  based upon the participating columns, data volume, indexing structure, and the set of values in the participating columns. So it generally the best approach in performance over the procedural cursor approach.

Here is an article on [Cursors and how to avoid them.](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them)  It also discusses the alternatives to cursors.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the articles!

Comment: I'm HTH on Stackoverflow when I can.  It's bailed me out of some tough coding problems in the past and thank you for the upvote!

Comment: It helped me out yesterday (the static cursor). I even forwarded an article to a colleague of mine. He was scripting out what a static cursor does by default (creating a table in TempDB and loop though the set).

Answer (score 0):

Alernates for CURSOR in SQL server

```
1.While loop
2.Recursive CTE
```

Comment: Replacing a RBAR cursor approach with a RBAR while loop approach that simulates a cursor is [unlikely to help](http://bradsruminations.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/truth-about-cursors-part-1.html)

Comment: Agreed with @Martin. Also see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/01/26/the-fallacy-that-a-while-loop-isn-t-a-cursor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Alernates for CURSOR in SQL server
**1.** Use temp table. create any column  ID as identity column.
**2.** Use while loop to perform the operation.