# SQL Trigger not firing on update

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following trigger which should insert records in a junction table when an entry is updated in main table. but this trigger is not firing ( It was firing earlier)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trUpdateRegistrant]
ON [dbo].[hr_Registrants]
FOR UPDATE  
AS

DECLARE @RegistrantID INT, @CategoriesIDs VARCHAR(1000), @DesiredCategoriesIDs VARCHAR(1000), @LanguagesIDs VARCHAR(1000), 
    @CategoryIDsChanged BIT, @DesiredCategoriesIDsChanged BIT, @LanguagesIDsChanged BIT

DECLARE curRegs CURSOR FOR
SELECT I.RegistrantID, 
    I.CategoriesIDs, 
    I.DesiredCategoriesIDs, 
    I.LanguagesIDs,
    CASE WHEN D.CategoriesIDs <> I.CategoriesIDs THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CASE WHEN D.DesiredCategoriesIDs <> I.DesiredCategoriesIDs THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CASE WHEN D.LanguagesIDs <> I.LanguagesIDs THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM INSERTED I JOIN DELETED D ON I.RegistrantID = D.RegistrantID 
WHERE D.CategoriesIDs <> I.CategoriesIDs 
    OR D.DesiredCategoriesIDs <> I.DesiredCategoriesIDs 
    OR D.LanguagesIDs <> I.LanguagesIDs

OPEN curRegs;
FETCH NEXT FROM curRegs INTO @RegistrantID, @CategoriesIDs, @DesiredCategoriesIDs, @LanguagesIDs, 
    @CategoryIDsChanged, @DesiredCategoriesIDsChanged, @LanguagesIDsChanged;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @CategoriesIDs IS NOT NULL AND @CategoryIDsChanged = 1
    BEGIN
        -- delete existing rows at first
        DELETE dbo.hr_RegistrantCategories WHERE RegistrantID = @RegistrantID

        INSERT INTO dbo.hr_RegistrantCategories (RegistrantID, CategoryID)
        SELECT @RegistrantID, CAST(T.Data AS INT) 
        FROM dbo.hr_Split(@CategoriesIDs, '|') T
    END

    IF @DesiredCategoriesIDs IS NOT NULL AND @DesiredCategoriesIDsChanged = 1
    BEGIN
        -- delete existing rows at first
        DELETE dbo.hr_RegistrantDesiredCategories WHERE RegistrantID = @RegistrantID

        INSERT INTO dbo.hr_RegistrantDesiredCategories (RegistrantID, CategoryID)
        SELECT @RegistrantID, CAST(T.Data AS INT) 
        FROM dbo.hr_Split(@DesiredCategoriesIDs, '|') T
    END

    IF @LanguagesIDs IS NOT NULL AND @LanguagesIDsChanged = 1
    BEGIN
        -- delete existing rows at first
        DELETE dbo.hr_RegistrantLanguages WHERE RegistrantID = @RegistrantID

        INSERT INTO dbo.hr_RegistrantLanguages (RegistrantID, Language)
        SELECT @RegistrantID, CAST(T.Data AS INT) 
        FROM dbo.hr_Split(@LanguagesIDs, '|') T
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM curRegs INTO @RegistrantID, @CategoriesIDs, @DesiredCategoriesIDs, @LanguagesIDs, 
        @CategoryIDsChanged, @DesiredCategoriesIDsChanged, @LanguagesIDsChanged;
END

CLOSE curRegs;
DEALLOCATE curRegs;
```

Please suggest how to fix it ?

Comment: Is the trigger deactivated?

Comment: not sure, how can i check this ?

Comment: "how can i check this" - please see my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558871/sql-update-query-doesnt-fire-update-trigger-for-all-records/52565116#52565116

Answer (score 2):

Try to use AFTER UPDATE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_test]

ON [dbo].[test]
AFTER UPDATE 

AS BEGIN


END
```

Or check is the trigger active:

```
SELECT t.name, t.is_disabled 
FROM sys.triggers t
WHERE t.name = 'trUpdateRegistrant'
```

Comment: `FOR` and `AFTER` are exactly synonymous.

Comment: I tried AFTER UPDATE and it worked. @Damien_The_Unbeliever if they are same then why AFTER UPDATE worked ? I am testing insert trigger as well

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - All I can tell you is that they're the same thing. Check the documentation for [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx): "`AFTER` is the default when `FOR` is the only keyword specified."

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012, may be things are different in SQL server 2012 ?

Comment: Sorry, but when I was working with MS SQL Server 2005 SP2, I had a similar problem (with insert). The construction AFTER helped me.

Comment: @Devart what about insert trigger, it is also not fired ( with after indert as well) ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trInsertRegistrant]
ON [dbo].[hr_Registrants]
FOR INSERT 
AS

Comment: Check MSDN (possible this be helpful for you): AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are fired only once per transaction, a mass update, delete or insert is executed in a single transaction.

You may need to use a curser or a while to guarantee the trigger is fired for each row.

[Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor)