# Create indexes for all tables in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I know I can index a column in a table with the command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)
```

However, I have a database of 250 schemas with 10 tables each. How can I, **for each table**, check if a column exists, and then create an index for it (if it does exist)?

*I am using SQL Server 2012.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small variation on Banana's answer is to use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) to grab the final list of tables directly:

```
-- Define column to index.
DECLARE @coltoindex VARCHAR(20), @indexoptions VARCHAR(30)
SET @coltoindex = 'Id'
SET @indexoptions = 'UNIQUE'

--USE database_name
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tables
SELECT table_schema, table_name INTO #tables FROM information_schema.columns
    where COLUMN_NAME = @coltoindex

DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(30), @table VARCHAR(20), @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @schema = table_schema, @table = table_name FROM #tables
    SET @sqlCommand = '
            CREATE ' + @indexoptions + ' INDEX 
            idx_'  + @schema + '_' + @table + '_' + @coltoindex + '
            ON ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' (' + @coltoindex + ')'
    -- print @sqlCommand
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
    DELETE FROM #tables WHERE table_schema = @schema AND table_name = @table
END
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for an improved answer!

Comment: I would suggest that you might add a ` IF (SELECT count(*) FROM sys.indexes WHERE name='idx_'  + @schema + '_' + @table + '_' + @coltoindex) = 0` above the `SELECT TOP 1`, which stops it from dying if there's already an index on that table.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way of achieving what you want, is to [loop over all tables through `information_schema.tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130/2801037) and then create the index [if the row exists in that table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133057):

```
-- Define column to index.
DECLARE @coltoindex VARCHAR(20), @indexoptions VARCHAR(30)
SET @coltoindex = 'Id'
SET @indexoptions = 'UNIQUE'

USE database_name
--IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tables
SELECT table_schema, table_name INTO #tables FROM information_schema.tables
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(30), @table VARCHAR(20), @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tables) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @schema = table_schema, @table = table_name FROM #tables
    SET @sqlCommand = '
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns  
        WHERE [name] = N''' + @coltoindex + ''' 
        AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''' + @schema + '.' + @table + ''')) 
        BEGIN 
            CREATE ' + @indexoptions + ' INDEX 
            idx_'  + @schema + '_' + @table + '_' + @coltoindex + '
            ON ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' (' + @coltoindex + ')
        END'
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
    DELETE FROM #tables WHERE table_schema = @schema AND table_name = @table
END
```

Comment: Seems odd that you'd use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` for the tables, but then `sys.columns` for the columns.... once the ANSI standard view, once the SQL Server specific one....