# Query shows 1 less than what's available in the #temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

So let's say #temp has 4 rows, the output will be 3(should be 4), if it has 1, then output will be 0.

I'm not quite sure what's going on. Wondering if anyone can tell by looking at the query.

```
SELECT TH.TnnNumber,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT TL.DiscountCodeID) > 1 THEN 'Varies, View Tnn' ELSE CAST(MAX(DC.Value) AS NVARCHAR(50)) END AS Discount,
    CASE WHEN TS.SpinID > 4 THEN 'Has Specifics, View Tnn' ELSE TS.Value END AS Spin,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT TL.Commission_HMM) > 1 THEN 'Varies, View Tnn' ELSE CAST(MAX(ISNULL(str(TL.Commission_HMM, 12), 'Default Comm')) AS NVARCHAR(50)) END AS Commission_HMM,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT TL.Commission) > 1 THEN 'Varies, View Tnn' ELSE CAST(MAX(ISNULL(str(TL.Commission, 12), 'Default Comm')) AS NVARCHAR(50)) END AS Commission,
    TL.TnnID
FROM [DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_Header AS TH
LEFT JOIN [DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_LINE AS TL
    ON TH.TnnID = TL.TnnID
LEFT JOIN [DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_Spin AS TS
    ON TH.SpinID = TS.SpinID
LEFT JOIN [DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_DiscountCode AS DC
    ON TL.DiscountCodeID = DC.DiscountCodeID
INNER JOIN #temp AS T
    ON T.Tnn = TH.TnnNumber
GROUP BY TH.TnnNumber,
    TS.SpinID,
    TS.Value,
    TL.TnnID
```

Required output:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| TnnNumber | Discount |          Spin           | Commission_HMM |  Commission  | TnnID |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
|    902054 | 50-20-9  | Has Specifics, View Tnn | Default Comm   | Default Comm |  5855 |
|    907616 | 50-20-20 | Half                    | Default Comm   |            2 |  6111 |
|    910019 | 50-20-9  | Half                    | Default Comm   | Default Comm |  7015 |
|    915919 | 50-20-9  | Half                    | Default Comm   | Default Comm |  7015 |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

Actual output:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| TnnNumber | Discount |          Spin           | Commission_HMM |  Commission  | TnnID |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
|    902054 | 50-20-9  | Has Specifics, View Tnn | Default Comm   | Default Comm |  5855 |
|    907616 | 50-20-20 | Half                    | Default Comm   |            2 |  6111 |
|    910019 | 50-20-9  | Half                    | Default Comm   | Default Comm |  7015 |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

Values in #temp

```
Tnn
902054
907616
910019
915919
```

Right join:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| TnnNumber | Discount |          Spin           | Commission_HMM |  Commission  | TnnID |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
| NULL      | NULL     | NULL                    | Default Comm   | Default Comm | NULL  |
| 902054    | 50-20-9  | Has Specifics, View Tnn | Default Comm   | Default Comm | 5855  |
| 907616    | 50-20-20 | Half                    | Default Comm   |            2 | 6111  |
| 910019    | 50-20-9  | Half                    | Default Comm   | Default Comm | 7015  |
+-----------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+--------------+-------+
```

Comment: Post source data, required and actual output. Script is fine, I like it.

Comment: Are you certain that the values in `#temp` are unique?

Comment: They are unique for sure, also if #temp has 1 value.. then the output is 0.. so it's skipping the last record for some reason.

Comment: You could use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to format your tables

Comment: Without the source data we can only guess. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) You also can post a working sample using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: If I use cursor as specified in this post, it correctly outputs 4 records:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470618/sql-server-how-to-output-one-table-result-from-multiple-results-with-a-while-que

Comment: Looks like the problem is `TH` doesnt have the same rows as `#TEMP` and `INNER JOIN` is removing one row.  Try with `RIGHT JOIN #temp AS T` and let me know the output

Comment: Updated the result with 4 records this time, but it's showing the last `TnnNumber` as `NULL`

Comment: I think it needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` for `#temp`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` resulted in 4531 rows, all the Tnn number are unique too.. strange?

Comment: Actually, I think @JuanCarlosOropeza was correct about the `RIGHT JOIN` now that I look at the query again. BUT, you need to change your SELECT to be from `T.Tnn` instead of `TH.TnnNumber`.

Comment: I assume `TnnID` is unique but two different `TnnNumber` must link the same row with `TnnID=7015` - how is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `RIGHT JOIN` query show your

```
[DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_Header AS TH
```

Doesn't have the row with `ID = 915919` that is why `RIGHT JOIN` return `NULL` and `INNER JOIN`  return a row less

try

```
SELECT *
FROM [DBSERV].Tnn.DBO.Tnn_Header AS TH
WHERE TH.TnnNumber = 915919
```

Now you have to check how are you creating `#temp` and validate you are using the same `ID` related to `Tnn_Header`

Comment: You are correct, I was assuming the cursor output was correct, but it isn't. We are in a development sql server so some data might be missing.