# SQL Server How to output multiple results into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I hope you are all ok, Although this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35470618/8446002) is similar, or for some people completely identical.But I haven't been able to reproduced the same output. This is my stored procedure. You can see the original stored procedure [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58).

In the `While` section is the section that returns the values, but it's returning the results separated. Like this:

[ImageInHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvx5.png)

What I want is this:

```
Select * 
From [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] 
Where id In (Select parsename(@tmpTblname, 1) 
             From SearchTMP)
```

to put all results in the same table instead of being separated

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SearchTables] 
    @SearchStr NVARCHAR(60),
    @GenerateSQLOnly Bit = 0,
    @SchemaNames VARCHAR(500) ='%' 
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    DECLARE @MatchFound BIT 

    SELECT @MatchFound = 0 

    DECLARE @CheckTableNames TABLE (Schemaname sysname, Tablename sysname) 

    DECLARE @SearchStringTbl TABLE (SearchString VARCHAR(500)) 

    DECLARE @SQLTbl TABLE (Tablename SYSNAME,
                           WHEREClause VARCHAR(MAX),
                           SQLStatement VARCHAR(MAX),
                           Execstatus BIT) 

    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @TableParamSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @SchemaParamSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @TblSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @tmpTblname sysname 
    DECLARE @ErrMsg VARCHAR(100)

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@SchemaNames)) ='' 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @SchemaNames = '%' 
    END  

    IF CHARINDEX(',',@SchemaNames) > 0  
        SELECT @SchemaParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@SchemaNames,',','''as SchemaName UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 
    ELSE 
        SELECT @SchemaParamSQL = 'SELECT ''' + @SchemaNames + ''' as SchemaName ' 


        SELECT @TblSQL = 'SELECT SCh.NAME,T.NAME 
                  FROM SYS.TABLES T 
                  JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SCh 
                  ON SCh.SCHEMA_ID = T.SCHEMA_ID 
                  INNER JOIN [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] et on 
                     (et.Id = T.NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)  '            


        INSERT INTO @CheckTableNames 
        (Schemaname,Tablename) 
        EXEC(@TblSQL)  

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @CheckTableNames) 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No tables are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
        PRINT @ErrMsg 
        RETURN  
    END  

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@SearchStr)) ='' 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @ErrMsg = 'Please specify the search string in @SearchStr Parameter' 
        PRINT @ErrMsg 
        RETURN 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN  
        SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,',,,',',#DOUBLECOMMA#') 
        SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,',,','#DOUBLECOMMA#') 

        SELECT @SearchStr = REPLACE(@SearchStr,'''','''''') 

        SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT ''' + REPLACE(@SearchStr,',','''as SearchString UNION SELECT ''') + '''' 

        INSERT INTO @SearchStringTbl 
        (SearchString) 
        EXEC(@SQL) 

        UPDATE @SearchStringTbl 
           SET SearchString = REPLACE(SearchString ,'#DOUBLECOMMA#',',') 
    END 

    INSERT INTO @SQLTbl 
    ( Tablename,WHEREClause) 
    SELECT QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(ST.NAME), 
            ( 
                SELECT '[' + SC.Name + ']' + ' LIKE ''' + REPLACE(SearchSTR.SearchString,'''','''''') + ''' OR ' + CHAR(10) 
                  FROM SYS.columns SC 
                  JOIN SYS.types STy 
                    ON STy.system_type_id = SC.system_type_id 
                   AND STy.user_type_id =SC.user_type_id 
                  CROSS JOIN @SearchStringTbl SearchSTR 
                 WHERE STY.name in ('varchar','char','nvarchar','nchar','text') 
                   AND SC.object_id = ST.object_id 
                 ORDER BY SC.name 
                FOR XML PATH('') 
            ) 
      FROM  SYS.tables ST 
      JOIN @CheckTableNames chktbls 
        ON chktbls.Tablename = ST.name  
      JOIN SYS.schemas SCh 
        ON ST.schema_id = SCh.schema_id 
       AND Sch.name        = chktbls.Schemaname 
     WHERE ST.name <> 'SearchTMP' 
      GROUP BY ST.object_id, QUOTENAME(SCh.name) + '.' +  QUOTENAME(ST.NAME) ; 


      UPDATE @SQLTbl 
         SET SQLStatement = 'SELECT * INTO SearchTMP FROM ' + Tablename + ' WHERE ' + substring(WHEREClause,1,len(WHEREClause)-5) 

      DELETE FROM @SQLTbl 
       WHERE WHEREClause IS NULL 

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0) 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT TOP 1 @tmpTblname = Tablename , @SQL = SQLStatement 
          FROM @SQLTbl  
         WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0 

         IF @GenerateSQLOnly = 0 
         BEGIN 

            IF OBJECT_ID('SearchTMP','U') IS NOT NULL 
                DROP TABLE SearchTMP 

            EXEC (@SQL) 


            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SearchTMP) 
            BEGIN 
                --SELECT parsename(@tmpTblname,1) FROM SearchTMP 
                SELECT @MatchFound = 1 
                Select * from [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] where id in (SELECT parsename(@tmpTblname,1) FROM SearchTMP )
            END 

         END 
         ELSE 
         BEGIN 
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
             PRINT @tmpTblname 
             PRINT REPLICATE('-',100) 
             PRINT replace(@SQL,'INTO SearchTMP','') 
         END 

         UPDATE @SQLTbl 
            SET Execstatus = 1 
          WHERE Tablename = @tmpTblname 
    END 

    IF @MatchFound = 0  
    BEGIN 
        SELECT @ErrMsg = 'No Matches are found in this database ' + DB_NAME() + ' for the specified filter' 
        PRINT @ErrMsg 
        RETURN 
    END 

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

What I tried to solve this problem: I was trying to make unions, but I haven't being able to achieve the desired outcome. Could you please, help me with this, please?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a temp table/table variable to hold the results of each execution within the while loop (as they are executing as separate batches, which will always return as separate result sets).

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (id VARCHAR(200), name VARCHAR(200)) 

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SQLTbl WHERE ISNULL(Execstatus ,0) = 0) 
    BEGIN
    ...

        SELECT @MatchFound = 1

        INSERT INTO @output (id, name)
        Select * from [DynaForms].[dbo].[Enums_Tables] where id in (SELECT parsename(@tmpTblname,1) FROM SearchTMP )

    ...

    END 

    ...

SELECT * FROM @output
```

This will only work if the resultset from each select statement is the same (e.g. always id, name), plus check the datatypes are correct as I've had to guess.