# Iterate through every row and create new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

Suppose I have the following table `T1`:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
|------|------|------|
| 0    | 1    | 1    | // 1
| 1    | 0    | 1    | // 1
| 0    | 1    | 0    | // 0
```

I now need to iterate every row, create a new table `T2` and populate it with a `1`, whenever there are two `1` in a row in `T1`.

So the new table `T2` would look like:

```
| res |
|-----|
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 0   |
```

Should I really iterate through each row, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor), or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: But why do you want to do something like that?

Comment: @jarlh: This is a very simplified version of my actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add up the "1"s.  Assuming each column is either 0 or 1 (as in the question):

```
select (case when col1 + col2 + col3 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as res
from t1;
```

Add `into t2` after the `select` if you really want another table.

Note:  SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets (unless there is an `order by` for the creation of a result set).  So, if you create a new table, the rows are unordered and will not correspond to the original data.  You might simply want a query like this:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when col1 + col2 + col3 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as res
from t1;
```

Comment: Ok, that solves the problem described here, thank you. But my description was very simplified and I expected something with several IF-Statements. I will have to place another question with a better description.