# Remove some characters of a column from a table type variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get a table type variable like this

```
color
-------------
Black
Blue&lt;br/&gt;PMS 285C
Green&lt;br/&gt;PMS 360
Red&lt;br/&gt;PMS 199
```

I want to make them like

```
color
-------------
Black, Blue, Green, Red
```

But I am having a very difficult time to remove the "&lt.." stuff.
I followed this answer: [Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor)
To create a temp table to loop and remove the characters, but still does not work

```
DECLARE @result int, @i int = 0, @colors varchar(800);
DECLARE @results table(color varchar(40));
INSERT INTO @results SELECT color FROM...

DECLARE @temp table(Id INT, color varchar(40));
INSERT INTO @temp SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id, color FROM @results

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) FROM @temp WHERE color like '%&lt%') > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT Top 1 @i = Id FROM @temp WHERE color like '%&lt%'
    UPDATE @temp Set color = (case when color like '%&lt%'
                         then left(color, charindex('&lt', color) - 1)
                         else color
                    end) Where Id = @i
    Delete @temp Where Id = @i
END
```

I still get

```
color
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Black, Blue&lt;br/&gt;PMS 285C, Green&lt;br/&gt;PMS 360, Red&lt;br/&gt;PMS 199
```

Could anyone help me please? Or give some suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `left()` with `charindex()` to get the left part of each value 
before the `&`; and uses the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
select stuff((
  select ', '+left(color,charindex('&',color+'&')-1)
  from @temp
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'')
```

test setup:

```
create table temp (color varchar(32))
insert into temp values 
 ('Black')
,('Blue&lt;br/&gt;PMS 285C')
,('Green&lt;br/&gt;PMS 360')
,('Red&lt;br/&gt;PMS 199')

select stuff((
  select ', '+left(color,charindex('&',color+'&')-1)
  from temp
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'')
```

returns: `Black, Blue, Green, Red`

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TWESQZ38491

Reference:

- [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL - Anith Sen](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Another version base on previous answer

```
    create table temp (color varchar(32))
    insert into temp values 
     ('Black')
    ,('Blue&lt;br/&gt;PMS 285C')
    ,('Green&lt;br/&gt;PMS 360')
    ,('Red&lt;br/&gt;PMS 199')



    declare @var varchar(max)
    set @var=''
    select @var=@var+case when charindex('&',color)=0 then color 
        else left(color, charindex('&',color)-1) end +', ' from temp
    select left(@var, len(@var)-1)
```