# What is best alternate for cursor in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a design concern which I need to implement without using cursor.

There is source table 'A' which will have all column in `varchar` data type. I want to iterate over them and convert each column to destination table data type and if conversion/parsing fails, I need to log that row in extra error table.

Any suggestions to go ahead will be helpful.

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include sample data as DDL + DML and desired results.

Comment: its sql server 2012 v11

Comment: Thanks all for your response. Still my main concern is to avoid cursor to iterate over the table as I have to record error for individual row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to loop through a table variable in TSQL without using a cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967/is-there-a-way-to-loop-through-a-table-variable-in-tsql-without-using-a-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you would use `try_convert()`:

```
insert into t2 ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from (select try_convert(?, col1) as col1,
                 try_convert(?, col1) as col2,                
          from staging_t
         ) t
    where col1 is not null and col2 is not null and . . .;
```

Then run a second query to get the rows where the value is `NULL`.

If `NULL` is a permitted value in the staging column, then this is a bit more complex:

```
insert into t2 ( . . . )
    select new_col1, new_col2, . . .
    from (select try_convert(?, col1) as new_col1, col1,
                 try_convert(?, col1) as new_col2, col2,              
          from staging_t
         ) t
    where (new_col1 is not null or col1 is null) and
          (new_col2 is not null or col2 is null) and
          . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

Example of all `varcharcol` that would fail conversion to int:

```
 select id, varcharcol
 from a
 where try_convert(int,varcharcol) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Above Query Using User Define Table Type

Create Type Table - Procedure - User Define Table Type

@UserDefineTypeTable UserDefineTypeTable readonly

insert into table1
col1,
col2,
col3

(select

type.col1,
type.col2,
type,col3

from @UserDefineTypeTable as type)